# Expected declaration error in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let time = NSDate();

@IBOutlet weak var DateLabel: UILabel!

func changeToActualDate() -> String {
    NSDateFormatter().dateFormat = "dd-MM";
    var formatteddate = NSDateFormatter().stringFromDate(time);
    DateLabel.text = formatteddate;
}

changeToActualDate();
}
```

I'm trying to get the date and I want to use it in a label (iOS-Application). Whenever I try to use the function 'changeToActualDate();', I get the follow error:

> Expected declaration

It's probably a dumb, beginner question. But what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @EricAya is right.

Comment: It's not "dumb", but it has been asked and answered many, many times on Stack Overflow already. Please search first, before asking. Save time and bandwidth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call your function in `viewWillAppear(animated:Bool)()` or `viewDidLoad()`

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let time = NSDate();

@IBOutlet weak var DateLabel: UILabel!

override func viewWillAppear(animated:Bool)(){

      super.viewWillAppear(animated:Bool)
      changeToActualDate()
    }

func changeToActualDate() -> String {
    NSDateFormatter().dateFormat = "dd-MM";
    var formatteddate = NSDateFormatter().stringFromDate(time);
    DateLabel.text = formatteddate;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That helps a lot.

Comment: Does it make a difference whether I put that line into viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad?

Comment: In this case it won't have a difference, but in general it will. You should read about the view controller lifecycle and when the different methods are called.